# embedded .jsp link in xml file

Tags: c#, xml, jsp

I have a list of items (real products) in .xml file. Every item has a node with short information.

For example:

```xml
<VENDOR_NAME>DELL</VENDOR_NAME>
<GROUP_NAME>PC Notebook Consumer</GROUP_NAME>
<CURRENCY_CODE>USD</CURRENCY_CODE>
<RETAIL_PRICE>963.62</RETAIL_PRICE>
<WARRANTYTERM>36</WARRANTYTERM>
<PRODUCT_CARD>https://content.it4profit.com/itshop/itemcard_cs.jsp?ITEM=180627115225381327&THEME=asbis&LANG=ro</PRODUCT_CARD>
```

My problem:
Instead of getting technical specs from `<PRODUCT_CARD>` with information like: CPU Core Quantity, Storage, Display, Software and so on, I have to manually go to that link, copy all information and paste into marketplace/online store.

I talk about thousands products and I can`t do it manually.

What I want to accomplish is:

- get all information about a product with all technical specification. In that list of items you can find products like: desktops, notebooks, peripherals, and so on.
- insert all this information into DataGridView (using c#).
- export data that I need to .xls file. In exported file I don`t need all Technical Specification of a notebook, for example. Maybe I want only specs about storage, ram and display. So, I am talking about custom export.

This method load the .xml file and populate DataGridView with `<VENDOR_NAME>`, `<GROUP_NAME>`, `<CURRENCY_CODE>` and so on, but, again, I only see a link when `<PRODUCT_CARD>` is loaded. I need technical specification instead.

```cs
private void xmlFileBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (openFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {
            string filePath = openFile.FileName;
            using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
            {
                ds.ReadXml(filePath);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["PRICE"];
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(
                "Select a valid file",
                "Try again", 
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
    }
}
```

[let me show you the way it look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckHDE.jpg)

Comment: Well, you have to download the web page from the specified URL, and parse it. You can find some help here: https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/jsoup-html-parsing-library.html

Comment: The dataset ReadXml() method does not work well when the xml file has lots of layers.  The data is fragmented onto multiple datatables that cannot be recombined.  You need to use a different method to parse your files.